# tkinter - Can't use a vertical scrollbar with a label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a label with a vertical scrollbar, using code similar to this:

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.geometry('480x320')
scrbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL, width=28)
scrbar.place(x=450, y=52)
lbl = Label(master, text=('A'*100), yscrollcommand=scrbar.set)
lbl.place(x=10, y=10)
scrbar.config(command=lbl.yview)
master.mainloop()
```

When running this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    lbl = Label(master, text=('A'*100), yscrollcommand=scrbar.set)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2590, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2089, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-yscrollcommand"
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use a widget that supports a scrollbar. The Label isn't such a widget. If you only need to scroll horizontally you can use an Entry widget and just set the state to disabled after setting the text.

If you need to scroll vertically, you can use a Text widget. You can also use a canvas with either a text item drawn on the canvas, or a label embedded in the canvas (search for how to do a scrollable frame; the solution is the same even though it's a label rather than a frame)

Comment: This technically doesn't answer the question. However, since there seems to be no answer, this is correct. Thank you!

Comment: @LehGogh: if it doesn't answer the question, don't accept it. Though, I don't know how else anyone could answer the question. Labels were never intended to scroll, they simply don't support it.

Comment: If I didn't accept this answer, this question would never have a correct answer. You said it yourself: Labels don's scroll. Plus, I found the 'use a text widget' option to be better than a mere label.